# Dynamically set the size of TableViewCell with swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am setting heights of tableView cells statically for each cell with this code.

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

if let cell = modelCollection[collection.identifier] {
            if let _ = cell as? TiteCell{
              return 200
             }else if let _ = cell as? ParagraphCell{
              return 500
             } else if let _ = cell as? WebViewCell{
              return 1000
             }
}
```

I don't want to set the static value 1000 for the WebViewCell anymore but the height of the website requested with the WebView. The problem is that I am requesting the website in another class called WebViewCell after setting the height on the DetailViewController Class. Is that possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the `viewDidLoad` use

`tblView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tblView.estimatedRowHeight = 200`

and remove `heightForRowAtIndexPath` datasource method. Also don't forget to use `AutoLayout` in `UITableViewCell`.

For more info check http://www.appcoda.com/self-sizing-cells/

Comment: must use Autolayout for this

Comment: but one should achieve dynamic height by your answer

Comment: I can't remove heightForRowAtIndexPath, I need it for the other cells, I want to set the dynamic height only for WebViewCell

Comment: I think that's not possible. Either you should use dynamic height or use static height.

Comment: It is possible Poles. By using both  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat and  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, EstimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloa

Comment: @ZonilyJame : Then how will you control which delegate method should be fired for different cells?

Comment: Look at my answer

Answer (score 0):

You could do it by doing this

Also don't forget to use NSLayoutConstraints cause this won't work without it

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

     if let cell = modelCollection[collection.identifier] {
            if let _ = cell as? TiteCell{
              return 200
             }else if let _ = cell as? ParagraphCell{
              return 500
             } else if let _ = cell as? WebViewCell{
              return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
             }
     }


 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, EstimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
     return 1000
}
```

Note: sorry if my answer formatting sucka. i'm using my phone at the moment

Comment: Why are using `heightForRowAtIndexPath` delegate methods twice?

Comment: @Poles The other delegate is 'estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath' not 'heightForRowAtIndexPath'

Comment: @user567 : You can try this.

Comment: @user567 don't forget to use NSLayoutConstraints for the `WebViewCell`